# how to create/get an instance of an custom service in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware

For some reason I do not fully understand how to get an simple instance of an custom service.
Here is the documentation which I have followed so far:

[https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/writing-data)

```
 class WritingData
{
    private $productRepository;
    private $taxRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository, EntityRepositoryInterface $taxRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->taxRepository = $taxRepository;
    }
}
```

the services.xml is also set

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <services>
        <service id="Swag\BasicExample\Service\WritingData" >
            <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
            <argument type="service" id="tax.repository"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

The question is: how do I may get an instance of the WrtingData inside my Command Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject your custom service into your command service just like you injected the repositories into `WritingData`. You can find more information about the container and dependency injection in [the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).

For example if this is your command service:

```php
class ExampleCommand extends Command
{
    private $writingData;

    public function __construct(WritingData $writingData)
    {
        $this->writingData = $writingData;
    }
}
```

Then you inject `WritingData` into `ExampleCommand` in `services.xml`:

```xml
<service id="SwagBasicExample\Command\ExampleCommand">
    <argument type="service" id="Swag\BasicExample\Service\WritingData"/>
    <tag name="console.command"/>
</service>
```

Comment: Thank you Pawel, but what about the the fact that the Command-Service already requires an parameter of type string. Do I have to to adapt it somewhere or just place the WritingData as second parameter instead?

Comment: @ChristianFelix you just place the WritingData as the second parameter in the constructor and as the second argument in `services.xml`. See for example the `InvoiceGenerator` [here](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/5f5dbdfd50d348f6f6fc0c6f182cbe270d61bf11/src/Core/Checkout/Document/DocumentGenerator/InvoiceGenerator.php#L30) and [here](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/5f5dbdfd50d348f6f6fc0c6f182cbe270d61bf11/src/Core/Checkout/DependencyInjection/document.xml#L16).

Comment: @PawełNapierała I'm still having issues with this, could you maybe help me out? I understand how to pass the service I want to my command, but what should I write for the other (`$name`) argument? The example you shared passes `%kernel.project_dir%` which I'm assuming is just some string from the container as well. But what about this one specific for the command? PS: I know this is an old post, but it's the only reference Google could find for this problem.

Comment: @rmobis I can't help you because I don't know what is the `$name`. Can you explain? It would be good to create a new question and paste your code.

Comment: @PawełNapierała Right, my bad. In the context of injecting a service into a new command, which extends `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command`. The extended class accepts a `string $name` in the constructor, so my extension should also accept it and pass it on to the `parent::__construct($name)`. How do I do that AND inject a service into the second parameter? That is, my class constructor signature would be `__construct(string $name, SomeService $service)`. To be honest I think the answer is you can't, but if you do know, let me know.

Comment: @rmobis for a command just set the name in the class variable `$defaultName`. Then you don't have to pass it in the constructor. See for example https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/c69b815bb578adea3acc15d106de9a12ec2600a8/src/Core/Framework/Store/Command/StoreDownloadCommand.php#L31